# Is it possible to provide find2perl mindepth and maxdepth arguments?

Tags: perl

I don't see the [`find2perl`](https://metacpan.org/module/find2perl) documentation mentioning anything about support for `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` arguments.

The example below works fine with [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

```
$ find2perl . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*txt" -type f
Unrecognized switch: -mindepth
```

Questions:

- Does `find2perl` support such functionality?
- If so, how can I specify `mindepth` and `maxdepth`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I love that your question's ID starts with `1337`. :)

Comment: Neither are mentioned in the docs. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @ikegami : I have tried it. The switches are unrecognized.

Comment: @memowe : Pardon my ignorance, but what's the significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Find-Rule) has these options, and it has a command line program [findrule](https://metacpan.org/module/findrule).

If you want to do it with File::Find, you can implement maxdepth by checking the depth of the file and setting `$File::Find::prune` when you've gone too deep.  mindepth is similar, but you return from your function early.  I'm feeling lazy this morning, so I'll leave the coding to someone else.

UPDATE: Somebody else did the programming, namely File::Find::Rule.  [Here's the code they use](https://metacpan.org/source/RCLAMP/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm#L542).

```
my $maxdepth = 2;
my $mindepth = 2;
my $topdir   = "something/something/something";
sub wanted {
    # figure out the relative path and depth
    my $relpath = $File::Find::name;
    $relpath =~ s{^\Q$topdir\E/?}{};
    my $depth = File::Spec->splitdir($relpath);

    defined $maxdepth && $depth >= $maxdepth
       and $File::Find::prune = 1;

    defined $mindepth && $depth < $mindepth
       and return;

    ...your code goes here...
}

find \&wanted, $topdir;
```

Comment: Looks like `F::F` wasn't set up to handle these switches in the first place. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

I just looked through the source code for find2perl, and for File::Find, which is the directory traverser that find2perl uses.  Neither mindepth nor maxdepth are presently implemented.

File::Find appears track depths as it traverses directories, in a variable called $CdLvl.  It is possible that you could implement mindepth and maxdepth by comparing against $CdLvl.

Comment: That's a lexical variable internal to File::Find.  Can't get at it.

Comment: I was subtly encouraging OP to add the feature to F::F.