# How to recursively in perl readdir contents starting from root and then according to a user specified level retrieve files that end in .txt

Tags: perl, recursion, tree, directory, subdirectory

I was trying to ask for help I posted [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128738/in-perl-how-to-use-recursion-to-search-directories-and-sub-directories-and-speci). Also I don't want to use any modules unless it is a built in module I prefer to write my own. I know the recursive part to list all files from multiple directories, but don't understand where exactly or how I would specify the desired level of search, so if I give as parameters root and 3 it should look through at least 3 directories and then retrieve all files as long it is less than or equal to 3. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Re "I prefer to write my own." Then why are you asking us to write it?

Comment: Wait, are the questions really "How do I pass a parameter to a function?" and "How do compare that value against `$level`?" You already know how to do the first, and you were already told how to do the second.

Comment: If you already have one part going, why not past it and show us where you are stuck. That will probably make answering a lot easier. And it would certainly feel less like a code request as well.

Comment: ok sorry guys I was just trying to ask for suggestions. I did post code, I'm not trying to ask you to code it, but appreciate the feedback anyways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you just want it to list all files, or to return them in an array.  If merely printing them is enough, you do something like:

```
sub print_txt_recurse() {
    my ($filepath, $level) = @_;
    #some code to get file paths and and print txt files going through each file
    elsif (-d $file && $level > 1 ) {
        print_txt_recurse($file, $level - 1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), a core module of Perl, which means it supposes to be available everywhere.

See [Core modules (F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html)